# Differences between shell type and core type transformers

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism

What is the advantage of a shell type transformer over core type and which one has smaller flux leakage?

Comment: The title and body of this question seam to ask different questions.

Comment: Have a look at https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for help on asking a good question for this site.